Outlook not using profile photo in AD for some users
We recently took new profile pictures of our employees. We uploaded these to Active Directory (using cjwdev's Ad Photo Edit Free Edition tool). This has worked for most users (and we've been using for years for new users).
For some users, the new photo will not show in Outlook. It continues to show the old photo. I can verify in several non-Outlook places that the picture is correct in AD (i.e. our intranet directory which pulls from AD, Office 365 online where it synced from on-prem AD) but it will not use these users' photos to other user's Outlook.
Current environment:

On-Prem Windows Server 2022 domain controllers running 2016 domain functional level.
Email accounts are in Exchange online.
On-Prem AD is synced using AD connect to Exchange online/Office 365.
Verified that the pictures that were uploaded were 96x96 pixels and less than 100KB
We have an on-prem hybrid Exchange server that we use (via scripting) to add some of the AD pieces when creating new users. None of our email data is stored on-Prem.

In my search, I have found a lot of people with the same issue, but all the posts are outdated with solutions that either don't help, or are no longer relevant and none of them ever acknowledged they found a solution to their issue. Any assistance would be appreciated.
